# Iphone UITableView, Cells, and notifications - cells not displaying correct image after notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So I'm stumped on this subject and not sure what the best way to do this is.  I need to download from an api, store in core data, then display a set of cells of a tableview with just a title, description and picture (the picture is a url, so I need to download that too).  The tableview only has one section

I have set up a structure where in my TableViewController I'm making self.tableview a listener to an NSNotification (specified during init).  I have created a custom cell view, with an extra property called firstLoad that gets set to YES during initialization.  In my tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath, I'm checking for the firstload property, and if it's set to yes, I'm calling a function to download the image from the url.  When that happens, a notification is sent out, caught by a function in the tableviewcontroller, I get the indexpathsforvisiblerows and if the row from the notification matches the row from one of the indexpathsforvisiblerows array, i set the cell's image and then reloadData

What i'm having troubles with is that when I start scrolling the tableview, it looks like sometimes the images get set for the wrong cell.  The cells are also being reused.

I'm not sure how to handle this exactly.  Thanks so much for any help!!

This is the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"APCell";

  APTableViewGenCell *cell = (APTableViewGenCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[APTableViewGenCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier useType:_useType] autorelease];
  }

  // Configure the cell...

  if (APUseTypeGroupsWithEvents == _useType) {
    APGroup *group = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = group.name;
    UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"groups.png"];
    if (group.logo.imageURL && (cell.firstLoad == (BOOL *)YES)){
      cell.imageView.image = [logoImage scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(kTableImageWidth, kTableImageHeight)];
      APGroundControl *gc = [APGroundControl sharedGroundControl];
      [gc retrieveImageWithURL:group.logo.imageURL indexPath:indexPath withDefaultImgName:@"groups" andDefaultImgType:@"png" sender:self];
    }


    cell.detailTextLabel.text = group.groupDescription;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  }

  return cell;
}
```

And this is the notification received handler:

```
- (void)imageRetrieved:(NSNotification *)notification {
   NSLog(@"%@", @"NOTIFICATION RECEIVED");
  if ([[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:kNewImageDownloadedSenderKey] isEqual:self]) {
    // If the cell is still visible show the image.
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:kNewImageDownloadedIndexPathKey];
    if (indexPath) {
      NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
      for (NSIndexPath *path in indexPaths) {
        if (indexPath.row == path.row) {
          APTableViewGenCell *cell = (APTableViewGenCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
          NSData *imageData = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:kNewImageDownloadedDataKey];
          UIImage *logoImage = nil;
          cell.firstLoad = (BOOL *)NO;
          if ([imageData isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
            logoImage = (UIImage *)imageData; 
            logoImage = [logoImage scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(kTableImageWidth, kTableImageHeight)];
            cell.imageView.image = logoImage; // @todo: get rid of this temp check once all image gets moved over to the new retrieve function
          }
          else {
            logoImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];            
            logoImage = [logoImage scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(kTableImageWidth, kTableImageHeight)];
            cell.imageView.image = logoImage;//[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
  }
}
```

And the code for retrieveImageWithUrl:

```
- (void)retrieveImageWithURL:(NSString *)url indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPathOrNil withDefaultImgName:(NSString *)defaultImgName andDefaultImgType:(NSString *) defaultImgType sender:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"%@", @"RETRIEVE IMAGE CALLED");
  NSLog(@"%@", indexPathOrNil);
  [self queueBlock:^{
    NSData *imageData = nil;

    // Get image locally
    if ([url isEqualToString:kGetGroupDefaultLogoURL]){
      NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:defaultImgName ofType:defaultImgType];
      imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    }
    // @todo: add a default user logo
    else if (url == nil) {
      NSLog(@"%@", @"Default Retrieve");
      NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:defaultImgName ofType:defaultImgType];
      imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    }
    else {
      NSLog(@"%@", @"Local Retrieve");
      imageData = [_imageCache objectForKey:url];
    }

    // If local image does not exist get it from the internet
    if (imageData == nil) {
      NSLog(@"%@", @"Remote Retrieve");
      NSLog(@"URL = %@", url);
      imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
      if (imageData == nil) {
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:defaultImgName ofType:defaultImgType];
        imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
      }
      [_imageCache setObject:imageData forKey:url];
    }

    // Send out notification
    NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray array];
    if (indexPathOrNil) {
      [objects addObject:indexPathOrNil];
      [keys addObject:kNewImageDownloadedIndexPathKey];
    }
    [objects addObject:sender];
    [keys addObject:kNewImageDownloadedSenderKey];
    [objects addObject:imageData];
    [keys addObject:kNewImageDownloadedDataKey];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSLog(@"%@", @"NOTIFICATION SENT");
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNewImageDownloadedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    });
  }];
}
```

Comment: This sounds as if filling the reused cells is somehow buggy. However, without any code it will be hard to help you. The code for cellForRowAtIndexPath and everything that belongs to it would be most helpful, I guess.

Comment: @Phlibbo just updated with code samples!  Thanks for taking a look!!

Comment: Well, frankly your code looks a little messy but I am trying to make sense of it. You know how reusing cells works, don't you? Even if you have 100 rows in your table, there might only be 6 Cells, which are used again and again. So, i think there is something wrong with your 'firstUsed' property. You use it to see if an image was already loaded, right? But if you have only e.g. 6 cells (with six 'firstUsed') properties but 100 images, something will go wrong :) I hope I am correct here and there might be other bugs but have a look at this first.

Comment: @Phlibbo totally agree with the messiness comment.  I'm an iphone n00b :)  I definitely agree with you that it's a bug, and I may just used an incorrect design pattern.  But the reason I used the pattern is because otherwise it gets thrown into a loop where it's constantly calling the retrieve function and reloading the view, and calling it again.  Can you think of a way around this?

Comment: Hey. Later this day, I'll post a proper answer. Just in short: Create an NSDictionary and store URL-Image Pairs in it. This way, you can just look in your dict if the image is already loaded. Store url-nil, if you are currently loading it.

Comment: @Phlibbo Gonna play around with that :)  Looking forward thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Phlibbo actually, the person that worked on it before already implented this.  I'm going to update the question with the retrieveImageWithUrl code.  The _imagecache is an NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all, the `firstLoad`-flag that you are using doesn't make sense. You need to know whether your image was already loaded but since reusable cells can't be connected with a specific image, this is not the way to do that.

You updated your post a few times and by now, it isn't exactly clear what your current problem is. So I'm just going to lay out the way for a proper and clean solution for you:
First of all, you need a place to store your images. A `NSMutableDictionary` will serve just fine. Use the keys to store your URLs and the value to store the images.
When you enter a new cell, look if the URL is already in the dictionary. If so, just fill it in. Otherwise, start the loading process. If you do so, you should also create a new entry in the dictionary, which stores the URL and `nil` for the image. This helps you to avoid loading an image with is not yet ready twice. In your 'Loading complete' method, you replace the `nil` value with your image.
And this should be it. Naturally, you will need to tailor these steps according to your specific needs, but this shouldn't be much of a problem. Hope this helps!

PS: Also, you should review your code to find redundant or overcomplicated calls. Without knowing you specific setup, iterating over an `NSIndexPath` looks pretty odd, you should be able to access your values directly.

Comment: first thanks so much for the response.  However, if you notice, that's exactly what's being done in the retrieveImageWithUrl function above.  I did get it working though, by creating an imageCache property on the tableview itself and keying it by indexpath. That way retrieveImageWithUrl is never run unless there's no object for that index path.  And I got rid of the firstLoad, you were right about that.  Also, lol how do you pull the values out of indexpath directly instead of the for loop?  I looked at the docs and couldn't get a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the cells which are getting dequeued from the table view keep the image that they had in their previous life. Try setting the imageview image to nil in cellForRowAtIndexPath (before updating it to its new image which could take some time).

Comment: ahh but if i set the image to nil on the cell, then I'd have to set the firstLoad prop of the cell to YES as well, so that the image could be loaded.  And that would throw the controller into an endless loop